# appropriate regression model to choose

Tags: predictive-models

I am having experimental data wherein variable a (categorical) and variable b(continuous) impact the resultant variable. I have limited data and both the datasets are non-normal. which regression method shud be chosen for modeling and predictions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you know about the resultant variable? // What regression models would you consider valid? Are you determined to use generalized linear models? Deep learning? Random forests? // The usual regression methods don't care about the distributions of the predictors.